# Eclipse - Project Gets Nonexisting Errors

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am currently using Eclipse with C/C++, installed straight from the Eclipse website. For some reason, my project ("DDSAssign2") won't run because of errors in the project, although my one source code file doesn't have any errors. It just shows up on the project icon in the Project Explorer. I had this problem this summer on occasion with Eclipse Juno and the Android Development tools, but that seemed to always mean that there was an error in the Manifest file, something I know shouldn't exist with C++, although I think it might mean there might be some file that has errors, but I just have the source file, MinGW includes, and the executable binaries and executable for debugging.

Here's the code. The editor for the code itself gives no errors, and this was running earlier. The red error icon only shows up on the Project Explorer for the entire project.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

struct stud
{
int id;
double gpa;
char className;
struct stud *next;
};

struct stud *add(struct stud *top);
void show(struct stud *top);

int main()
{
struct stud *top = NULL;
srand(time(NULL));

int x = 0;
while (x == 0)
{
    top = add(top);
    cout << "Press [0] to continue, any other integer to quit.";
    cin >> x;
}
show(top);
return 0;
}

struct stud *add(struct stud *top)
{
struct stud *dum;
dum = (struct stud *)malloc(sizeof(struct stud));
cout << "What is the student's ID?" << endl;
cin >> dum->id;
cout << "What is the their GPA?" << endl;
cin >> dum->gpa;
cout << "What is their class?" << endl;
cin >> dum->className;

if (top == NULL)
{
    top = dum;
}
else
{
    while (top != NULL)
    {
        if (top->next == NULL)
                        top->next = dum;
        if (dum->id < top->id)
        {
            struct stud *dum2 = top->next;
            if (dum->id < dum2->id)
            {
                dum->next = top->next;
                top->next = dum;
            }
        }
        top = top->next;
    }
}
return top;
}

void show(struct stud *top)
{
if (top == NULL)
{
    cout << "Stack is empty.";
}
while (top != NULL)
{
    cout << "ID: " << top->id << endl;
    cout << "GPA: " << top->gpa << endl;
    cout << "Class: " << top->className << endl;
    top = top->next;
}
}
```

Another thing I'm wondering is if it's because of the name of the project. I've remade this "DDSAssign2" project a few times now, trying to get rid of this problem, and the last time I wasn't able to delete the contents on the workspace from Eclipse, so I just had to do it manually.

Comment: Can you show us this 'errorless source code file'?

Comment: Done. I added some more information about that and the project.